# Object not getting added to array, redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an action which is to be used to add an object to the end of an array, but when I trigger the onPress that will run the action it always comes back with an error `item.image not found` , That means it isn't seeing the newly added object's property `image`, Please what I'm I doing wrong and why isn't it adding the object with the properties to the array

**The Action**

```
export const addCart = newItem => ({type:
"ADD_CART", payload: newItem
});
```

**THE REDUCER AND INITIAL STATES**

```
const initialState = {
cartItems: [{
    image: 'img/lappy.png',
    name: 'Hand Bag',
    amount: '100000',
    id: 4
}]
};
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
case ADD_CART: 
        return{
           ...state,
           cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.newItem]
        };
```

**THE BUTTON THAT TRIGGERS THE ACTION**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        amount: '',
        description: '',
        qty: '',
        images: [],
        id: ''
    };
}
carter(){
    this.props.addCart(
        {image: this.state.images[0],
        name: this.state.name,amount: 
        this.state.amount,
        id: this.state.id});      
}
 <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.carter.bind(this) }>
                               <View style={styles.addToCart}>
                               <Text style={{fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'mont-medium', color: '#fff'}}>
                                   ADD TO CART
                               </Text>
                               </View>    
                              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

**ITEMS, i.e items.images**

```
const cartItems = (
    <FlatList
        data={this.props.cartItems}          
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => ( 
            <View style={styles.productbox}>

<TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail', {})}>
            <Image  resizeMode="contain" style={{borderRadius: 3,
width: 90,
height: 69,
marginLeft: '9%'}}
source={{uri: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/'+item.image}}/>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>

<View style={styles.productTextBox}>
 <Text style={styles.productName}>
  {item.name}
 </Text>
 <Text style={styles.productPrice}>
  ₦{item.amount}
 </Text>
</View>

 <View style={styles.chatter}>
 <Image  resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
 source={require('../chatter.png')}/>
 </View>
 <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() =>this.props.removeCart(index)}>
 <View style={styles.chatter2}>
  <Image  resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1,}}
source={require('../cancel.png')}/>
 </View></TouchableNativeFeedback>
  </View>    
         )}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}                
    />
    );
```

Comment: where is item.image in your code?

Comment: @Think-Twice please check I have updated the code

Comment: We don't see dispatch. Make sure you do dispatch, and not just create action to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correction is required in reducer. In actions you are returning newItem as payload but in reducer you are  accessing action.newItem Instead of action.payload which is incorrect

Add below change in reducer and try

```
 case ADD_CART: 
    return{
       ...state,
       cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload]
    };
```

Also in ITEMS add below change

```
 <FlatList
    data={this.props.cartItems}          
    renderItem={( item, index) => (
```

Comment: Thanks @Think-Twice , you were the first to answer :)

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene No Problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Your action is dispatching an object with this shape:

```
{
  type: "ADD_CART", payload: newItem
}
```

That means in your reducer you should get the new data via:

```
action.payload
```

And not:

```
action.newItem
```

So the correct reducer should look like this:

```
case ADD_CART: 
        return{
           ...state,
           cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload]
        };
```

Comment: That's exactly what I answered 7 mins ago :)

Comment: @Think-Twice that's great

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the use of the `bind` function. As the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) says:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value

Thus, here, when you press the button, you are not calling the method, but creating a new one. You should move the `bind` call to the `constructor` (and don't forget to assign its return value!) and simply do this `onPress={this.carter}`  to call your function on press.

Maybe it would be wise to add some log in your code to see what's happening, redux can get quite confusing in the beginning :)

Comment: Moving it to the constructor would be good so as to only bind the function once, but the problem you describe isn't happening. The current code is binding it when render is called, not when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes function binding always should happen in constructor only and not anywhere else in the component